# cannot generate code for file

Tags: oop, gcc, real-time, ada, gnat

Please have a look at the following code

**Formula.ads**

```
package Formula is
   procedure CalculateFormula;
end Formula;
```

**Formula.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Formula; use Formula;

package body Formula is
   procedure CalculateFormula is

      package fom_io is new Ada.Float_Text_IO(Float);
      use fom_io;

      u : Float;
      t : Float;
      a : Float;
      answer : Float;

   begin
      put_line("Enter 'U'");
      get(u);

      put_line("Enter 'T'");
      get(t);

      put_line("Enter 'A'");
      get(a);

      answer = (u*t)+ 0.5(a(t*t));

      put("Answer is: ");
      put(answer,Fore => 1,Aft => 1,Exp => 1);
   end CalclualeFormula;
end Formula;
```

When I run this code, I get the following error

```
gnatmake -d -PC:\Users\yohan\Documents\Ada\Formula\formula.gpr
gcc -c -I- -gnatA C:\Users\yohan\Documents\Ada\Formula\formula.ads
cannot generate code for file formula.ads (package spec)
gnatmake: "C:\Users\yohan\Documents\Ada\Formula\formula.ads" compilation error

[2013-04-06 03:18:22] process exited with status 4 (elapsed time: 00.22s)
```

I am very new to Ada. Started coding few hours back. Please help me to get rid of the above issue. Thank you.

**EDIT**

**formula.gpr**

```
project Formula is

   for Main use ("formula.ads");

end Formula;
```

Comment: I think we need to see your .gpr file. But a couple of points : a package body doesn't need to "with" it's own spec. And while you can compile a .ads file (spec) to check syntax, you can't generate code from it, which is what the error msg suggests is happening. Normally you would just compile your main program unit, and all necessary package compilations just happen automagically.

Comment: your Main needs to be a procedure (body)

Comment: Why have you tagged this 'oop'? (and 'real-time', come to that?)

Comment: Additionally to others replies, you don't need to with/use the package specification from a package body, that's implied: you can and should remove `with Formula; use Formula;` which you added in the body of `Formula`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPR file shows that you are trying to use a package specification as a main program unit - that doesn't work.

Two ways to fix this: The simplest one is to make "CalculateFormula" a standalone main program in a file "calculateformula.adb" and set this in your project file:

```
for Main use ("calculateformula.adb");
```

But if you want to see how packages work, there is a "better" way (in that it gets you to understand what packages are for and how they are used...)

Packages are reusable components : the package spec is all you need to see in order to use them ... but you actually use them in another program. So in this case you would create a main program

```
with Formula; use Formula;

    procedure MyMain is
    begin
       CalculateFormula;
    end MyMain;
```

and in the .gpr file,

```
for Main use ("mymain.adb");
```

And then the compiler will automatically compile the correct packages and find the other issues that Shark has pointed out.

You really don't need a separate Main here, as the "hello world" example showed. However such trivial "main subprograms" (in the correct Ada lingo) are not so unusual, especially for purposes like unit testing packages to be used in more complex apps later.

Comment: It's much better to stick to lower-case file names, at any rate for the Ada code. Windows doesn't care, Mac OS X can get confused, and other Unix systems pretty-much require it (you can work deep magic with a GPR `package Naming`, but why bother?)

Comment: Agree on lower case filenames : edited. Linux is case sensitive but some tools translate to lower case (perhaps to keep Windows happy) resulting in mismatches there too.

Answer (score 0):

This is puzzling because there are some big errors that the compiler should be flagging, like:

```
package fom_io is new Ada.Float_Text_IO(Float);
```

which isn't `with`ed, and

```
answer = (u*t)+ 0.5(a(t*t));
```

because:

1. `=` is not the assignment operator; you need `:=`.
2. 0.5(XXXX) isn't valid multiplication.

Also, there's exponentiation in Ada, so t**2 can replace t*t.

---

**`formula.adb`**

```
with
Ada.Float_Text_IO,
Ada.Text_IO;

use
Ada.Text_IO;

package body Formula is
   procedure CalculateFormula is

      use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

      u, t, a, answer : Float;

    Procedure Prompt( Item : out Float; Name : String ) is
    begin
        put_line("Enter '"& Name &"'");
        get(Item);
    end prompt;
   begin

    prompt( u, "U" );
    prompt( t, "T" );
    prompt( a, "A" );

      answer:= (u*t) + 0.5*( a*t**2 );

      put("Answer is: ");
      put(answer,Fore => 1,Aft => 1,Exp => 1);
      New_Line;
   end CalculateFormula;
end Formula;
```

This corrects the syntax errors you had. The other answer seems right in that this ["cannot generate code for" error] seems to be a problem with the gpr-file rather than the source itself.

Comment: Yes, but it's still weird that there's nothing about them.... though on further inspection this seems to be a case of bad error-messages [though Ada in-general tends to have helpful messages] it seems to be saying "this specification file cannot be used to create an executable/object [generate code]"... under certain circumstances a spec can gen an object (pure/enumerations, IIRC).

Comment: @Shark8: A spec can generate an object *provided that* it doesn't require a body; this one does. I do agree that in an ideal world `gnatmake` would tell us that a package spec can't be a main program.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I already gave you a +1. Thanks a lot for the good code, I learnt a lot from it.

Comment: Anyway, The output I get is in mathematical notations 'Answer is: 3.4E+2'. How can I get normal numbers?

Comment: Ask that question separately and I'll post an answer.